# Need help for user experience database with user levels

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm not totally newbie but also not the master of php&mysql, now I'm using Codeigniter for my website.

I arranged some user xp points for some events for website when you add question to website you are earning 10 points, if you wrote answer you are getting 20 points. etc..

So my user_xp table has these columns:

---

```
user_id    xp_points    level
```

---

So I'm just curious to make 40 different levels for my users between different points, so I don't want to calculate them again again 40 time by if cases, so if anyone has idea it will help me alot. (If every level was same point it will be easy but higher levels should be more difficult is'nt it?)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some [Geometric Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) to calculate the level based on the user's XP.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to implement this in PHP?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954874/php-game-formula-to-calculate-a-level-based-on-exp)

Comment: Thanks for help but could you give me more clue about it?

Answer (score 0):

if or switch case, no way out =) ,  byu you need encapsulate it in one place, like helper,  and make something like 
function getUserLevel($xp_points) {  .... return $level; }

Comment: so I need one helper that will calculate my levels with my conditions so in another case we will use if or switch case but only in helper :)